# memory in javafx candlestick chart

Tags: java, performance, memory, javafx-2, jfreechart

I have developed two candlestick chart one using jfree and other using javafx 2.2

Both are adding one candle every 100 ms and I ran them(seprately) for around two hours and measure memory usage using jconsole.

I get around 400 Mb of used memory for jfree based chart and around 5Gb of used memory for javafx based chart.

What can be possible reason for javafx to use so much of memory where jfree chart (swing based) is doing same work (though with not so good graphics) in comparatively very low amount of memory.